# mvc4 Decimal more than 2 decimal places

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, decimal

How do I configure MVC4 to format all Decimals in my model with full processions?
I don not want to add DataAnnotations to all properties in my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a DisplayTemplate for decimal.

```
@model decimal

@Model.ToString("0.0000") // Or whatever format you're after...
```

Comment: Thanks. Additional notes. MVC4 supports Default Templates, you should just add the folder "EditorTemplates" in "Shared" view.